# ConfigError: Missing region in config when i am using amazon ses with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-ses

I have used an env file and i used the structure like this and getting this error how to resolve that

```
"AWS_SES_REGION":"us-east-1" and i have put us-west-2 also but still getting the same error
"AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID":"value"
"AWS_SECRET_KEY":"value"
```

and here is the code which i am using to send the email can anyone suggest me how to solve this problem

```
require('dotenv').config();
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');


const SESConfig = {
    apiVersion:"2010-12-01",
    accessKeyId:process.env.AWS_SECRET_KEY,
    accessSecretKey:process.env.AWS_SECRET_KEY,
    region:process.env.AWS_SES_REGION   
}

// AWS.SESConfig.update({region: 'eu-central-1'});

var params = {
    Source: 'xyz045@gmail.com',
    Destination: {
      ToAddresses: [
        'yyy45@gmail.com'
      ]
    },
    ReplyToAddresses: [
      'xyz05@gmail.com',
    ],
    Message: {
      Body: {
        Html: {
          Charset: "UTF-8",
          Data: 'IT IS <strong>WORKING</strong>!'
        }
      },
      Subject: {
        Charset: 'UTF-8',
        Data: 'Node + SES Example'
      }
    }
  };

  new AWS.SES(SESConfig).sendEmail(params).promise().then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
  }).catch(error => {
      console.log(error)
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to load the config using the `AWS.Config` class.

**Example:**

```
require('dotenv').config();
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');



const SESConfig = {
    apiVersion: "2010-12-01",
    accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_SECRET_KEY,
    accessSecretKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_KEY,
    region: process.env.AWS_SES_REGION
}

let config = new AWS.Config(SESConfig); // Load the configuration like this. 
/*
Or you could update the config like this.
AWS.config.update(SESConfig);
*/


var params = {
    Source: 'xyz045@gmail.com',
    Destination: {
        ToAddresses: [
            'yyy45@gmail.com'
        ]
    },
    ReplyToAddresses: [
        'xyz05@gmail.com',
    ],
    Message: {
        Body: {
            Html: {
                Charset: "UTF-8",
                Data: 'IT IS <strong>WORKING</strong>!'
            }
        },
        Subject: {
            Charset: 'UTF-8',
            Data: 'Node + SES Example'
        }
    }
};
new AWS.SES().sendEmail(params).promise().then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
}).catch(error => {
    console.log(error)
});
```